# apply custom validation annotation to parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have the following classes used for validating a password.

```
public class PasswordConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassword, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidPassword constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String password, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator(Arrays.asList(

                // at least 8 characters
                new LengthRule(8, 30),

                // at least one upper-case character
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase, 1),

                // at least one lower-case character
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase, 1),

                // at least one digit character
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit, 1),

                // at least one symbol (special character)
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Special, 1),

                // no whitespace
                new WhitespaceRule()
        ));

        RuleResult result = validator.validate(new PasswordData(password));

        if (result.isValid()) {
            return true;
        }

        List<String> messages = validator.getMessages(result);
        String messageTemplate = messages.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(messageTemplate)
                .addConstraintViolation()
                .disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordConstraintValidator.class)
@Target( {ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidPassword {
    String message() default "Invalid Password";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Adding the @ValidPassword annotation for a field in a class works.
However when I try adding the annotation to a parameter in a function, the validator is never called/reached.

```
public void resetUserPassword(Integer userId, @ValidPassword String newPassword) {
}
```

Also adding the annotation here doesn't work either:

```
@PostMapping("/user/resetPassword/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> resetUserPassword(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId, @Valid @ValidPassword @RequestBody String newPassword) {
    userService.resetUserPassword(userId, newPassword)
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I don't think I am missing any dependencies, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: I would have expected it to work with `@Valid` at least, but I nearly always have my data wrapped in an object, so I'm not as familiar with the "bare value" case as others.

Comment: Do standard constraint annotations like `@NotNull` and `@NotEmpty` work? Because if these don't work I wouldn't expect my custom annotations to work either.

Comment: Do you have your controller class annotated with @Validated annotation? If not please add the annotation on the controller class at class level.

Comment: @RobSpoor `@NotNull` and `@NotEmpty` also did not work so it makes sense why my custom annotation didn't work.

Comment: @Rishal Adding `@Validated` to the controller class worked for some reason. Thank you! I can't mark your comment correct but you can post it as a solution if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The annotation **@Validated** defined at class-level annotation is
> necessary to trigger method validation for a specific bean to begin
> with.

Also in other words

> The **@Validated** annotation is a class-level annotation that we can
> use to tell Spring to validate parameters that are passed into a
> method of the annotated class.

Refer this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11039 to find out the origin for `@Validated`

**Usage:**

As you have the below method with your custom annotation `@ValidPassword` with your `@Valid`

```
@PostMapping("/user/resetPassword/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> resetUserPassword(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId, @Valid @ValidPassword @RequestBody String newPassword) {
    userService.resetUserPassword(userId, newPassword)
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

**@Valid**

It is used for enabling the whole object validation As you can see in the below example the `@NotNull` `@Size` and `@NotBlank` will be invoked to validate the user input or supplied values present in the object.

Eg:

```
public class DummyUser{
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min =8)
    private String password;
 
    @NotBlank
    private String username;
}
```

**@Validated**

But, As per your case you want your custom validation to be invoked on the method parameter , Hence you need to provide the hint to spring to invoke the custom validation. So, to do that you have declare the `@Validated` annotation at class level in your controller.

So these are the reasons for your validation to start working after you have annotated your controller class with `@Validated` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@Validated` annotation on the controller class or another class, where you want to validate method parameter with your custom validation.

There was an explanation in [spring-boot 2.1.x documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-validation.html) about this kind of method-level validation, but I couldn't find it in current 2.7.x docs.

In general it's a spring-framework feature, that can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method). In a non-boot project you'll need to create a bean of type `MethodValidationPostProcessor` manually, but spring-boot auto-configurates this bean for you - the autoconfiguration can be found in [`ValidationAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.java#L70) class.

[According to java-docs of `MethodValidationPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html), *target classes with JSR-303 constraint annotated methods **need to be annotated with Spring's `@Validated` annotation at the type level**, for their methods to be searched for inline constraint annotations. Validation groups can be specified through `@Validated` as well. By default, JSR-303 will validate against its default group only.*